# create a combo box getting data using using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, combobox

I created a rest service which is giving a json output
{
 "area1": [
  "office_1",
  "office_2"
 ]
}

On UI I want to show both the keys and values of this json map in two different comboboxes.
i.e area1 in one combo box and office_1 and office_2 in another combo box.
But I am not available to achieve this
here's my combo box code

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
 <h5>Select the Domain:</h5>
 <form role="form">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="system">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
      <li ng-repeat="system in systems" class="input-lg">{{system.area}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: data is not coming in the drop-down

Comment: Also tried this                                                                                                   <div class="col-xs-6">
  <h5>Select the System:</h5>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-repeat="system in systems">
      <li>{{system.area}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: Please create a plunkr or something. ng-model and ng-repeat iterator value is same - `system` Try with different names

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/6z3G0fYsCbsj3BtehJi1?p=preview) what you are looking for?
not sure I understand your requirements but I've done this:

CTRL:

```
$scope.systems = { "area1": [ "office_1", "office_2" ] }
```

View:

```
<h5>Select the Domain:</h5>
 <form role="form">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="systems.area1">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
      <li ng-repeat="system in systems.area1" class="input-lg">{{system}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
 </form>
```

see results in [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6z3G0fYsCbsj3BtehJi1?p=preview).

Comment: thanks @jax
But i want both these values in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
      <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in systems.area1" class="input-lg">{{value}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is remain?? it display office1 and office2? what you need?

Comment: it is not displaying anything

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you have to change a little your json response to look like this:

http://www.w3schools.com/json/

So your json response will be something like this:

{ "area1": [ {"first_office":"office_1", "second_office":"office_2" }] }

In this way you will have access to your data via "first_office" and "second_office".

After all these you have to build your controller where you have to put your json response to $scope. I.e

```
$scope.result = response.area;
```

And then add a general div for the controller:

```
<div ng-controller="your_controller">
```

and inside the div

```
 <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
   <li ng-repeat="system in result.area1" class="input-lg">{{system.first_office}}</li>
 </ul>
 <ul id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
   <li ng-repeat="system in result.area1" class="input-lg">{{system.second_office}}</li>
 </ul>
```

end of the div

```
 </div>
```

Test in Plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/eY8O92sVlkn6HSOpe0sy?p=preview

Good luck.

Comment: You could create dropdown menus in this way:  [http://plnkr.co/edit/tP4wqRiI0TkYFZ2mAr1B?p=preview]